# Partial derivativePlane that fits the points

Tags: calculus

I need to find the plane which fits the 4 points given in such a way that the plane minimizes the sum of squares of the derivations. how should i approach this as i am really confused about it
$$(0,0,0) ,(0,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,0,-1)$$

i am given a the hints below but i have no idea. 
 how to approach this question .any help really matters alot.$$f(A,B,C)=\sum_{i=1}^4 (Ax_i+By_i+C-z_i)^2$$
Plane
$$z=Ax+By+C$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Since you want that $f(A,B,C)$ be minimum, write the derivatives with respect to $A,B$ and $C$ and set each of them equal to zero. You will end with three linear equations for the three unknown parameters. It will be very simple.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: how do i go about  getting the equation before i can do the partial derivative?

Comment: What are the derivatives of $f(A,B,C)$ with respect to $A,B,C$ ? Keep $x_i$,$y_i$ and $z_i$ notations up to the end.

Comment: which equation do i use to get the derivatives of A,B,C? do i use the one with the summation or the other?

Comment: Compute the derivatives of $f(A,B,C)=\sum_{i=1}^4 (Ax_i+By_i+C-z_i)^2$ with respect to $A,B,C$.

Comment: is it like this? $$f_A=2(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(x_i)$$
$$f_B=2(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(y_i)$$
$$f_C=2(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(1)$$

Comment: You are almost done ! Put the $\Sigma$ in front and notice that, since you want zero, you can divide each expression by $2$.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^4f_A=2(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(x_i)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^4f_B=2(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(y_i)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^4f_C=2(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(1)$$  do you mean that i should change from i=1 to i=0 by dividing by 2?

Comment: $f_A=2\sum_{i=1}^4(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(x_i)$ and the same for the other.

Comment: $$2\sum_{i=1}^4f_A=(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(x_i)$$
$$2\sum_{i=1}^4f_B=(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(y_i)$$
$$2\sum_{i=1}^4f_C=(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(1)$$ so i can just do linear equations with the 3 equations above? how do i go about eliminating $$x_i,y_i and z_i$$ Also what should i do from i=1 to i=4?

Comment: No. $$f_A=2\sum_{i=1}^4(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(x_i)=0$$ $$f_B=2\sum_{i=1}^4(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)*(y_i)=0$$ $$f_C=2\sum_{i=1}^4(Ax_{i}+By_i+C-Z_i)=0$$

Comment: ok, but what should i do with the summation? i can't just solve it with linear equation directly?

Comment: Expand the summations, put your numbers to get three linear equations in $A,B,C$

Comment: is it something like this ? $$f_a=2[(Ax_1+By_1+C-z_1)(x_1)+(Ax_2+By_2+C-z_2)(x_2)+(Ax_3+By_3+C-z_3)(x_3)+(Ax_4+By_4+C-z_4)(x_4)]$$
$$f_b=2[(Ax_1+By_1+C-z_1)(y_1)+(Ax_2+By_2+C-z_2)(y_2)+(Ax_3+By_3+C-z_3)(y_3)+(Ax_4+By_4+C-z_4)(y_4)]$$
$$f_c=2[(Ax_1+By_1+C-z_1)+(Ax_2+By_2+C-z_2)+(Ax_3+By_3+C-z_3)+(Ax_4+By_4+C-z_4)]$$

Comment: If you want ! Start dividing each equation by $2$ and collect all terms which are multiplied by $A$; same with $B$ and $C$. Now, replace the $x_i,y_i,z_i$ by their values.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by collect all terms which are multipled by A,B,C ?

Comment: Group the terms to get the coefficients which multiply $A,B,C$ in each of the equations.

Comment: do you mean like this? $$f_a=[(x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}+x_3^{2}+x_4^{2})A+(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4)B+(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)C+(-z_1-z_2-z_3-z_4)]$$

Comment: Yes. You made it ! By the way, it is exactly the same problem as fitting data along a straight line. Cheers.

Comment: ok so i just have to complete the other 2 functions and find A,B,C. but what do i do with the 4 points given?

Comment: Replace $x_1=0,y_1=0,z_1=0$ and so on.

Comment: $$f_a=[(x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}+x_3^{2}+x_4^{2})A+(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4)B+(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)C+(-z_1-z_2-z_3-z_4)]$$
$$f_a=[(0^{2}+0^{2}+1^{2}+1^{2})A+(0*0+0*1+1*1+1*0)B+(0+0+1+1)C+(-0-1-1-(-1))]=2A+B+2C-1=0$$
$$f_b=[(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4)A+(y_1^{2}+y_2^{2}+y_3^{2}+y_4^{2})B+(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4)C+(-z_1-z_2-z_3-z_4)]$$
$$f_b=[(0*0+0*1+1*1+1*0)A+(0^{2}+1^{2}+1^{2}+0^{2})B+(0+1+1+0)C+(-0-1-1-(-1))]=A+2B+2C-1=0$$
$$f_c=[(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)A+(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4)B+(4)C+(-z_1-z_2-z_3-z_4)]$$
$$f_c=[(0+0+1+1)A+(0+1+1+0)B+(4)C+(-0-1-1-(-1))=2A+2B+4C+-1=0]$$